# Retrieve data in the core php in the format of cakephp group by table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want to retrieve data in the format of **cakephp** like **group by** table (model)

Like:

```
select user.*,category.*,area.* from user 
left join category on user.cat_id=category.id
left join area on user.area_id=area.id

array(
     [0] => Array(
               [user]=>array(
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [user_name] => test user
                )
               [category]=>array(
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [category_name] => test cat
                )
               [area]=>array(
                    [area_id] => 1
                    [area_name] => area1
                )
     )
    [1] => Array(
               [user]=>array(
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [user_name] => test user
                )
               [category]=>array(
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [category_name] => test cat
                )
               [area]=>array(
                    [area_id] => 2
                    [area_name] => area2
                )
    )
)
```

Whenever we fire **join** query retrieves all data group by table.

So how to do that?

Table structure and values for table `area`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `area` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `area` (`id`, `a_name`) VALUES
(1, 'bapunagar'),
(2, 'bopal');
```

Table structure and values for table `category`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `category` (`id`, `c_name`) VALUES
(1, 'food');
```

Table structure and values for table `user`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `u_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `area_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`u_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `user` (`u_id`, `u_name`, `cat_id`, `area_id`) VALUES
(1, 'pragnesh', 1, 1),
(2, 'tejash', 1, 2);
```

Comment: Can you post an example with some data ?

Comment: @Rikesh question updated,please have a look

Comment: As far as I can tell, the two sub-arrays are identical. What's the point of that?

Comment: @NisseEngström My friend I want data in this format please don’t consider the data values :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code to achieve your desired array:

```
$sql = "select user.*,category.*,area.* from user left join category on user.cat_id=category.id left join area on user.area_id=area.id";
$res = mysql_query ($sql);

$finalArray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($res); ++$i) {
        $table = mysql_field_table($res, $i);
        $field = mysql_field_name($res, $i);

        $array[$table][$field] = $row[$field];
    }

    $finalArray[] = $array;
}
print_r($finalArray);    



Outputs as:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [u_id] => 1
                    [u_name] => pragnesh
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [area_id] => 1
                )

            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [c_name] => food
                )

            [area] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [a_name] => bapunagar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [u_id] => 1
                    [u_name] => pragnesh
                    [cat_id] => 1
                    [area_id] => 1
                )

            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [c_name] => food
                )

            [area] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [a_name] => bapunagar
                )

        )

    ...

)
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: it doesn't working, i have provided table and values please check out i have updated question.

Comment: @PragneshMca, I have tested my code with your tables and it gives me perfect result. have added the output to my answer.

Comment: @v2solutions.com thanks a lot, you made it so easy, you are master :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check if this solves your problem. I got wanted results, but please check does this suits you:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from user") or die(mysql_error());
$i = 0;
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $result[$i]['user']['user_id'] = $row['u_id'];
    $result[$i]['user']['user_name'] = $row['u_name'];
    $cat_query = mysql_query("select * from category where id = {$row['cat_id']}") or die(mysql_error());

$y = 0;
while($cat_row = mysql_fetch_array($cat_query)){
    $result[$i]['category']['category_id'] = $cat_row['id'];
    $result[$i]['category']['category_name'] = $cat_row['c_name'];
    $y++;
}// while
$area_query = mysql_query("select * from area where id = {$row['area_id']}") or die(mysql_error());
$z = 0;
while($area_row = mysql_fetch_array($area_query)){
    $result[$i]['area']['area_id'] = $area_row['id'];
    $result[$i]['area']['area_name'] = $area_row['a_name'];
    $z++;
}// while
    $i++;
}// while
// Here I just show results
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Just to mention. I used old fashion `mysql_connect`. You can use what ever you want(`PDO`, `mysqli`), but then you must fetch arrays differently, do query's differently...

Comment: @er-kt I don't know does this solve your problem, but it's closest that I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$this->loadModel('User'); //Load Model
$this->User->find('all',array(
    'joins' => array(
      array(
        'table' => 'category',
        'alias' => 'Categories',
        'type' => 'LEFT', //LEFT JOIN
        'conditions' => array(
            'Categories.id = User.cat_id'
        )
      ),
      array(
        'table' => 'area',
        'alias' => 'Areas',
        'type' => 'LEFT', //LEFT JOIN
        'conditions' => array(
            'Areas.id = User.area_id'
        )
      )
    ),
    'fields' => array('Users.*','Areas.*','Categories.*') //Display all the fields
));
```

Hope it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I know how to get data in cakephp,but i want to get data in core php in the same form as in the cakephp,thanks for your effort